# Asian romantic movie, with a woman dating two men who appear to be the same man until the film's end

Tags: identify-this-movie

I was flying to Thailand with Turkish Airlines and saw this Asian movie. I believe it is either Japanese or South Korean. The movie isn't on the airline's movie list any more. I remember that the title had the word "love" in it, and I think it only had two words in the title. Unfortunately, I could not find a matching movie with my search.

In the film, a girl and a boy are dating each other. The boy gets a job in a bigger city, so he moves. Every weekend, he drives back to see his girlfriend (at the beginning).

But he meets someone else at work (they start dating), and the original girlfriend also starts to date this really shy guy. However this "shy guy" falls in love with her and tries to change himself to be more appealing to her.

The movie does not reveal that she is dating this guy and has a boyfriend working in the capital. It is not until the end that it is revealed that she started to date this guy.

The movie is made really well, giving this impression that both of the guys are the same person until the very end.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV Stackexchange! Thanks for the awesome description. Hopefully one of us knows the answer. To help make it even easier to find the answer, is there any chance you can remember when you saw the movie? (Five years ago, last year, last week?) Or when you think it would have come out (1990s, early 2000s, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks! I saw it few months ago, unfortunately I cannot remember when it was published. However the movie didn't seem so old, so my guess would be maybe few years ago, at least after 2000. If I remember correctly they guy graduated from university so I would say the main characters were in their twenties.

Answer (score 4):

You probably watched the 2015 Japanese move [Initiation Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initiation_Love)

> Set in Shizuoka and Tokyo, Japan in the late 1980's. Suzuki (Shota
>   Matsuda) is a university student in Shizuoka attempting to find a job.
>   Mayu (Atsuko Maeda) is a dental hygienist. They meet through a blind
>   date and begin to date, but Suzuki finds a job in Tokyo and goes
>   there. They begin a long distance relationship, but their relationship
>   breaks down. - [Asianwiki](http://asianwiki.com/Initiation_Love)

I too saw it on a plane, then looked for it online and found your question. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the answer, this is great! :) Yes, that was the movie I was searching for.

Comment: @55555 Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) this answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.